# What etiquette, if any, is there for where the knot goes when wearing a yukata or kimono?

Tags: japan, clothing, cultural-awareness

When wearing either a yukata or a kimono, what etiquette, if any, is there about where the knot goes? Do only sex workers (whose work is illegal nowadays in Japan) deliberately wear a knot in front of them?

Wikivoyage [informs](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Japan#Ryokan) users not to wear right over left with their yukatas, as that's associated with the dead, but doesn't have anything about knots.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukata#Customs) that bows in the front of a yukata represents a sex worker, but doesn't have any citations backing it up.

[This guide](https://japaneseguesthouses.com/japanese-robes/) has a knot just off-centre in front of the person, while [this guide](http://visitkinosaki.com/hot-springs/yukata/) has a knot behind the person.

Comment: A kimono is to a yukata what tea ceremony is to your morning tea. Completely different things that really shouldn't be lumped together.

Comment: There isn't any concrete rules about where to wear the knot. It is basically personal choice. When staying at a hotel / Ryokan, most people tie the knot of the provided Yukata at the front (and I am pretty sure that most customers aren't prostitutes) as it is easier to take off when going to the Onsen / Sento (some people however still wear it at the back). However when wearing a Yukata to say, a summer festival, it is **most commonly** worn at the back, with modernising fashion senses slowing changing this norm.

Comment: Further, prostitution in Japan whilst "illegal", still happens on a large scale (and is usually disguised lightly by calling it something else). Most "houses of the night" don't usually have their female purveyors in Yukata / Kimono [citation unavailable]. Kimono on the other hand, are different in use to Yukata, mainly because of the meaning behind every piece of the Kimono (the sleeve length, designs, knot style, accessories, make-up etc.) which are used to declare status and marital availability of the wearer. In that sense, Kimono knot locations may give credence to your claim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first guide you cited shows a very simple yukata that you get at hotels and ryokans. It has little pieces of cloth attached to it to make it easy to secure it even without a belt (obi). Without a belt, you would typically just wear it inside, like a bathrobe or a pyjama.

The second guide shows how it's done *with* an obi, and there the knot (or bow) goes behind the back. This is for females however.
Men wear a very plain obi, and it's positioned at the hips, much lower than for women. As it's much plainer and thinner and the knot isn't as big, I think I've seen people wear it at all kinds of positions, but typically it also goes in the back, just do an [image search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%E7%94%B7%E3%80%80%E3%82%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F&iar=images&iax=1&ia=images) for "yukata men" to get a feeling.

I've never seen a woman wear the bow in front, and this would be really impractical. The wikipedia article says "historically", so I don't think it's being done any more.